# jquery slider will not scroll the whole div

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

Sorry to be a broken record....I've searched high anf low for this answer. Does anyone know if it even possible? Right now its the only stopping form launching the site. The slider is controlling 3 divs within a class. It only scrolls a little bit...does this have to do with the divs being differnt lengths?

This is the page I'm working on
www.kerrydean.ca/tizzest.html

This is the code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    $(".info").css("top", 0 
                   );
    // Reset slider to top

    var max = $("#slider-vertical").slider("option","max");
              $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", max);

});
  });

$(function() {
    var scrollPane = $('.info'),
        scrollableHeight = scrollPane.height() - scrollPane.parent().height() || 0;
  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "max",
      min: 0,
      max: scrollableHeight,
      value: scrollableHeight,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
      scrollPane.css({top: ui.value - scrollableHeight});
      }
    });
  });
```

Anyway help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
scrollPane.css({top: ui.value - scrollableHeight});
```

My guess is the slider's maximum value is less than the scrollable height. Try adjusting for the discrepancy with something like this:

```
ui.value * (scrollableHeight / maxValue) - scrollableHeight //put in your own maxvalue variable
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping out. So how would I implement this code in my exisitng code? as an option on its own, or within the scrollPane.css({top: ui.value - scrollableHeight}) line?

Comment: On the same line. Just replace my maxValue variable with whatever gets the max value of the slider.

Comment: Ok cool I tried this to no avail....is this what you meant? $(function() {
    var scrollPane = $('.info'),
        scrollableHeight = scrollPane.height() - scrollPane.parent().height() || 0;
  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "max",
      min: 0,
      max: scrollableHeight,
      value: scrollableHeight,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
      scrollPane.css({top: ui.value - scrollableHeight });
   ui.value * (scrollableHeight / 800) - scrollableHeight
   
      }
    });
  });

Comment: Not quite: slide: function(event, ui) {
      scrollPane.css({top: ui.value * (scrollableHeight / 800) -scrollableHeight});
      }

Comment: Ok I tried that....it seems like it wants to work, but it's doing something abit differnt now. I uploaded it here so you can see http://www.kerrydean.ca/tizzest.html#   thanks again -greg

Comment: try this instead, maybe... $("#slider-vertical").slider( "option", "value" ) * (scrollableHeight / maxValue) - scrollableHeight

Comment: No that didnt work either. Starting to think this is not gonna work. Maybe time to rethink the design....thanks a million for your help